# Maxima not returning any solutions for simultaneous equations.

Tags: maxima-software

Maxima returns no results for the following:

```
 solve ([a = (p-x)*c, b = (q-x)*d, a + b = 0], [x]);
```

I think it should return:

```
                       d q + c p
                  [x = ---------]
                         d + c
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it succeed if you replace $b$ by $-a$ and omit the equation $\,a+b = 0?\ $ Try $\,\rm assume(c+d\,\#\,0)\,$ beforehand.

Comment: No but if I perform the substitution by hand, i.e.

solve ([ (p-x)*c +  (q-x)*d = 0], [x]);

then it works as expected.

Comment: I couldn't get the assume(c+d # 0) to work. It doesn't like the '#' operator. I tried assume(notequal(c+d,0)) but it still returned no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a system of 3 equations of one variable `x`. Such a system can be overdetermined. Even

```
solve ([a = (p-x)*c, b = (q-x)*d, a + b = 0], [x]);
```

results in an empty solution

```
[]
```

because `a+b=0` isn't true except for special values of the constants `a` and `b`. A constant expression will be true in this context only if it can be proved that is true for all possible assignment to the parameters.

I think you actually wanted to solve the system

```
solve ([a = (p-x)*c, b = (q-x)*d, a + b = 0], [x, a, b])
```

with three variables `x`, `a`, `b` and the constants `c`,`d`,`p`,`q`.

Maxima calculates the solution

```
[[x = (d*q+c*p)/(d+c),a = (c*d*p-c*d*q)/(d+c),b = -(c*d*p-c*d*q)/(d+c)]]
```

where `x` has the value you expected.

Comment: Thanks. That works but I'm still not clear why.

You said 'a+b=0' is only true for special values but the solution maxima gives clearly shows a+b=0 in general.

Also 'solve ([ (p-x)*c + (q-x)*d = 0], [x]);' works as I would expect.

Comment: @Rob190  You have to distinguish between constants and variables. In the `solve([...,a+b=0],[x])` statement a and  b are not in the variable list `[x]`, so they are constants (or parameters). `a+b=0` is false because one cannot show that `a+b=0` for arbitrary values a and b (e.g. 3+5 !=0). If one statement is false in a system of equations then this system does not have a solution. In the statement `solve([...,a+b=0],[x,a,b])` a and b are in the variable list so Maxima tries to calculate the values of these variables such that all equations of this system of equations are true.